# Why isn't יה אלי said on days when Yizkor is said?

Tags: tefilla, yom-tov, song-poetry

On the 3 Festivals, Pesach, Shavuot and Succot, many Nusach Ashkenaz congregations say a poem called יה אלי before saying אשרי . But it is eliminated on days when Yizkor is recited.

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Check the Siddur haShelah. He authored י–ה ﭏי (after he retired from the rabbanut of Frankfurt a/M, where it was never adopted).

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt If you can locate this Siddur or a similar source that explains this, please post an answer.

Comment: יה אלי is also "mutually exclusive" with Av HaRachamim (which is always said after Yizkor, even though normally holidays are not a time to say tachanun and therefore Av Harachmim). Presumably it's a question of tone - we don't engage in rapturous "simcha inspired" praise in the same moment we're engaging in contemplation of death.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky "we don't engage in rapturous "simcha inspired" praise in the same moment we're engaging in contemplation of death." I don't know if one can generalize this adage. Look at what occurs in Israel each Simchat Torah. Hakafot and Yizkor on the same day. Likewise at the wedding, we break a glass. (may not be a great example.) There are other examples of when we do both one following the other.

Comment: @DanF True, which is why it's a comment not an answer. There's potentially a distinction to be made between a declaration of simcha imposed on a somber mood (יה אלי) and somberness imposed upon a simcha (breaking the glass, yizkor). Generally, we warn against excessive simcha but excessive somberness isn't *usually* a concern.

Comment: @danf yizkor and simchat Torah together is a new phenomenon. Yizkor was originally said on Yom Kippur and on days when kol habekhor is read. When Ashkenazim got to Israel they kept saying yizkor even though it didn't make sense because people are irrationally attached to it

Comment: @DanF, it's not in the Rödelheim machzorim. The authorship info is in the Sacks Siddur (Koren) and it's either in his siddur or a relative's publication in his name.

Comment: @DoubleAA, Matnat yad is tied to Kol haBechor, Yizkor to Y"K, the Shabbat before Shavuot, and Shabbat Chazon. See http://www.kayj.net/en/forum/minhogim/2305-leaving-for-yizkaur

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I never heard the term "Matnat Yad" until now. Very interesting link you placed, there. But, if Yizkor is tied to that concept, there is no Matnat Yad on Yom Kippur. Or is there a different reason for having it on YK besides Matnat Yad?

Comment: @DanF, all Ashkenazi kehillot say Yizkor on Y"K, due to the solemnity of the day. Polish Kehillot instituted Yizkor in place of Matnat Yad after the Chmielnicki uprising.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Shelah did not author this - it's already mentioned in the sefer haminhagim from [R' Isaac Tyrnau](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/8224-isaac-tyrnau)